# Android Fragments and SlidingMenu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am building an app that uses the slidingmenu library from:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

I have a design question about how to use fragments and activities with this menu pattern.

Option 1:  When the user clicks on a sliding menu option start a new activity that also implements the sliding menu.

Option 2: When the user clicks on a sliding menu option swap to a new fragment inside the main activity.  In this case I would essentially have one activity that hosts several different fragments which can be swapped in and out depending on what menu option the user picks.

Does any one see any pros / cons from the two above options or have a better option?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: You should use option 2. If you use option 1, the user will not see the SlidingMenu sliding to close.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone with option 2 for now.  Although this means that pretty much all the functionality in my app lives inside one activity (and the child fragments) but the main activity is getting complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends, but at a first glance the Option 2 seems more reasonable.

First of all because the Option 1 is more prone to code duplicate. Having each Activity implement the sliding menu, seem a bad design.

Secondly, Fragments can make your life a lot more easier when comes to configuration changes (such as screen orientation), as all your instance objects are destroyed if declared in an Activity and you should write code that saves and restore their state, while using Fragments you won't need to do that. Just declare `setRetainInstance(true)` and all your instance objects declared in the Fragment are retained.